# View *More* Entities in App Engine SDK Datastore Viewer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The default number of entities displayed in the App Engine SDK Datastore viewer is 10 entities. How do I get it to display more at once? Appending `?limit=100` doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm referring to the page found at [http://localhost:8000/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=[entity_type]](http://localhost:8000/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=%5bentity_type%5d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `limit=100` works, but only after navigating to a page after the first or changing the GQL query to execute - which adds additional parameters to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Append `num=100` to the url you mentioned, you can go up to 100 this way. If it's still not enough, take a look at `DatastoreRequestHandler.num()` method in `google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py`.

All this applies to SDK 1.6.1.